# What is the correct way to stop the test because nothing is being published using awaitillity

Tags: java, async-await, awaitility

I'm currently playing about with the awaitility function within my tests. I'm trying to post a message to my pubnub console. However this currently isn't happening due to the unsubscribe teardown I've implemented. I'm struggling with the syntax for the awaitility. I've got a couple of lines in to show you what I've been doing. Could someone point me down the right path?

```
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubException;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import service.PubnubService;
import static com.jayway.awaitility.Awaitility.await;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;




/**
 * Created by peterki on 07/09/2016.
 */
public class PublisherTest {

    private PubnubService service = new PubnubService();

    //Arrange method for all of the tests
    @Before
    public void setupConnection() throws PubnubException {

        // Setup Subscriber
        service.subscribe("my_channel");

        // Do nothing until the subscriber has connected.
        do{} while (!service.isConnected());

    }

    @After
    public void TeardownConnection() throws PubnubException {

        // Unsubscribe from channel after each test has completed. So that the next test isn't waiting so subscribe.
        service.unsubscribe("my_channel");

    }

    @Test
    public void testSportMessageType() throws PubnubException {


        // Publish to External Service
        service.publish("my_channel", "Hello Peter");

        //Wait till we receive the message
        await().until(); -> service.publish("my_channel"); == 1;
        await().until(() -> service.publish("my_channel", "Hello Peter")() == 1);

        // Assert the message is what we want

    }
}
```

Comment: Can close now solved.

Comment: You should add an answer if you've solved it